# 404 errors in Nuxt Production environment

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

My app works perfectly in dev mode, however I'm facing issues in the production environment.

My Folder Structure is like this pages > widget > _id.vue

For testing I just put a h1 tag in _id.vue file, when I run enter the url - https://app.mydomain.com/widget/xyz I get 404 errors on all files.

```
https://app.mydomain.com/widget/hhhhh 404
https://app.mydomain.com/_nuxt/dist/bf9e34c.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
https://app.mydomain.com/_nuxt/dist/eb32a87.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
https://app.mydomain.com/_nuxt/dist/cc2d21b.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

Here is my apps `nuxt.config.js` file code, unable to figure out what's the issue here:

```
        export default {
        // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
        server: {
            port: 8000 // default: 3000
        },
        target: 'server',
        head: {
            title: 'Title',
            meta: [
                { charset: 'utf-8' },
                { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
                {
                    hid: 'description',
                    name: 'description',
                    content: 'my website description'
                }
            ],
            link: [
    
                { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
                { href: '../assets/styles/style.css' }, { href: '../assets/styles/videoform.css' }, { href: '../assets/styles/tailwind-responsive.css' }, { href: '../assets/styles/tailwind-components.css' }
    
    
    
            ],
            script: [
                { src: 'https://js.stripe.com/v2/' }
            ]
        },
    
        // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
        //   <style>
    
        //   @import '../../assets/styles/style.css';
        //   @import '../../assets/styles/videoform.css';
        //   @import '../../assets/styles/tailwind-responsive.css';
        //   @import '../../assets/styles/tailwind-components.css';
        // </style>
        css: [
    
        ],
    
        // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
        plugins: [],
    
        // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
        components: true,
    
        // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
        buildModules: [
            // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/tailwindcss
            '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
            '@nuxtjs/composition-api'
    
        ],
    
        // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
        modules: [
            '@nuxtjs/axios',
        ],
    
        axios: {
            // proxy: true
        },
    
        // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
        buildDir: '_nuxt',
        build: {
            publicPath: '_nuxt/dist/'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When requesting those script files, nuxt uses the `build.publicPath` to find them. Your `buildDir` path tells nuxt to save the build files in `_nuxt`, while your `build.publicPath` tells nuxt that those files are located in `_nuxt/dist`. That's why you get a 404.

You can change the `build.publicPath` to match the `buildDir` to fix this. Or change the `buildDir` instead.

[Nuxt Docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-build#publicpath)

Comment: I changed the `buildDir` to - `buildDir: '_nuxt/dist/'`. Still I'm getting the same error

Comment: It should work that way. I can't reproduce your issue. Maybe it has something to do with how you deploy your site.

Comment: This helped me solve an issue when deploying to edgio. It was looking for `.nuxt` rather than the usual `_nuxt` directory name.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured out the problem, it was due to nginx configuration.

There was a trailing slash for the reverse proxy `http://localhost:8000/`

I had to remove that to fix the issue - `http://localhost:8000`